# How do I know what the parentheses refer to

Tags: javascript, new-operator

In the second statement, since the parentheses are optional, how do I know if the parentheses are part of the first constructor, the second, or if it is calling a function that does not do anything?

```
function A(){return function(){}}
new new A()
```

Comment: Did you put `new` **twice** on purpose?

Comment: Yes. I want to make it complicated to help me understand how this works.

Comment: You can add `console.log` before the return and inside the function to see what is called and when. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/pw946q7m/ (it seems that with one `new`, it doesn't call the function; but with `new new`, it does)

Comment: What is the explanation behind this behavior? Do I have to test all the time?

Comment: I'd say the explanation is that it is interpreted as `new ( new A() )`

Comment: You find out by reading the language specification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the precedence and associativity of the operators.
new with parentheses has higher precedence than function call and new without parentheses and the associativity is right so the parentheses goes to the right most new.